# How the CPU determines whether to put data in L1i or L1d

Tags: memory, cpu, memory-management, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

How does CPU decides what cache to use to store data just retrieved from memory?

As far as I know the smallest unit of memory that CPU can access (read or write) is 64 Bytes (x86_64, DDR3/DDR4) which is transmitted in burst of 8 transfers (64 bits x 8-times). This 64B unit is called Cache Line because it is upon arrival immediately stored into L1 (each entry is 64B + tag).

Compiled code is full of instructions and data interleaved - a lot of instructions have the data as part of the instruction itself - there is Opcode followed with the immediate data. Is this considered whole as an instruction and thus stored in L1i? Are both L1i and L1d entries 64B wide? Is the whole cache line stored in either L1i or L1d? Or is it that CPU is aware of C's .data segment and only data from that portion of program is stored in L1d? If so how does it know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does CPU decides what cache to use to store data just retrieved from memory?

The CPU does not have to *"decide"* which cache to use.  The cache assignment is wired into the processor cache logic.  The CPU knows why and what each memory access is for.

> Compiled code is full of instructions and data interleaved ...

That is a faulty assertion.
I've used computers that blended code and data sections, but that predated the arrival of microprocessors.
Modern CPU architecture uses a hardware stack to facilitate recursion and serial re-entrant code.
Modern toolchains generate separate text (i.e code) and data sections to facilitate code sharing.

A salient characteristic of the Harvard computer architecture is separate memories for code and data.
Although most widely-used computers follow the Princeton or von Neumann archetecture, the modern trend has been to incorporate aspects of Harvard architecture.
The use of separate caches for instruction and data (but a single main-memory address space) is an obvious example.

> ... a lot of instructions have the data as part of the instruction itself - there is Opcode followed with the immediate data.

That is an inaccurate description of instruction format.
A CPU instruction is composed of an opcode and zero or more operands.

- An opcode such as HALT would have no operands.
- An operand could be a reference to the contents of a register, or the value of the operand itself (aka immediate or literal value).  Such an instruction would not generate a (data) memory operation.
- An operand could be a memory address, or reference to the contents of a register as a memory address, or an address offset.  There could be additional operands for an address mode and/or register(s) to specify the memory address calculation.  Such an instruction would generate a (data) memory operation wh*en executed*.

> Is this considered whole as an instruction and thus stored in L1i?

The instruction is composed of an opcode and zero or more operands.
Until the instruction is decoded (especially for *fixed-length* RISC instructions), the operand portion of the instruction is a mystery, and could not be segregated by any cache logic.
So of course the entire instruction has to be kept as a single entity, and would have no involvement with the data cache (until the instruction is executed).

The instruction cache only holds memory locations fetched as instructions.
The memory addresses of these instructions would be specified by the PC (Program Counter register).
If the CPU employs branch prediction logic, then that could be another source of addresses of instructions.

All other memory references would be considered accesses for data.

---

> As far as I know the smallest unit of memory that CPU can access (read or write) is 64 Bytes (x86_64, DDR3/DDR4) which is transmitted in burst of 8 transfers (64 bits x 8-times). This 64B unit is called Cache Line because it is upon arrival immediately stored into L1 (each entry is 64B + tag).
>   ...
>   Are both L1i and L1d entries 64B wide? Is the whole cache line stored in either L1i or L1d?

Cache sizes are CPU implementation dependent.
You are inaccurate in attempting to generalize about such specifications.
There are many other (modern) CPU architectures and implementations that do not resemble what you describe or claim to *"know"*.

---

> Or is it that CPU is aware of C's .data segment and only data from that portion of program is stored in L1d? If so how does it know?

No, the CPU is not aware of the memory organization, but rather knows why and what the memory access is for.
Memory accesses that use addresses from the Program Counter (PC) register (and other possible logic) are for instructions, and utilize the instruction cache.
The *execution* of an instruction can generate a memory access for data, and that memory access will utilize the data cache.
Even if code and data were not segregated by software-generation tools, the CPU would still be able to use separate code and data caches, albeit with unpredictable results when read/write data cache overlaps with read-only instruction cache.

Comment: your comment + [this question about variables and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446171/how-do-compilers-assign-memory-addresses-to-variables) (and some other googling) helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data and instructions may be interleaved on the bus and higher level caches, but the CPU knows the type of data it is dealing with at any given moment.

Bytes will be streamed out of the L2 cache and the types of instruction can be identified and monitored. Program flow can be inferred and watched and adjusted for and cache can be flushed as necessary. From the first instruction executed by a CPU it can see the "instruction stream" and therefore what needs to go into the instruction cache.

#### What gives it that first instruction?

In any computer the first thing it gets is an instruction. The first thing a CPU will do is go to a particular address and grab a handful of bytes. Historically this will be a ROM device but it could just as easily be a memory mapped device in the PCH that passes the CPU its startup instructions and microcode.

The pointer for the current (and therefore most likely next) instruction is a register in the CPU known as the [Program Counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter). It is constantly updated as instructions are executed.

Indeed the first few instructions could simply be "set the program counter to xxxxxxxxx" at which point the processor would switch to grabbing instructions from that location, where another memory device might live.

From there the CPU always has visibility of the instruction stream. It can see instruction after instruction, branches, checks and so on. When the operating system halts the CPU and restarts the CPU it will load the program counter with the exact location of the instructions to begin executing.

From there the CPU again can look ahead and see the instruction stream and what needs to be loaded into the instruction cache.

For everything that is left there is the data cache.

Answer (score -1):

The distinction between data and code needs to be made very carefully: Consider this sniplet:

```
i=i+10;
```

That will increase a variable by 10. Now the important part is, that no matter of which value `i` has, the increment will always be `10`. This means, that we should consider `i` as data as it might change during execution of the porgram, but `10` as part of the code (as it will not).

This implies, that the machine code resulting from compilation of that sniplet will have `i` referenced as either a register or a memory location, but `10` as immediate data. Since we consider this immediate data to be part of the code, we put it into the instruction cache.